# Autohotkey loop down key/folder-files

Tags: autohotkey

I want to add +1 to {Down} after starting the next loop

```
F8::
stop := 0


Loop, 13
{
    Run, "C:\Users\USER\Desktop\docs"
    Send {Home}
    Sleep 1000
    Send {Down} ;Here i want to add +1 after loop start again
    Sleep 2000
    Send {Enter}
    Sleep 2000
    Send !{F11}
    Sleep 2000
    Send {F5}
    Sleep 2000
    Send !{f4}
    Sleep 2000
}until Stop
return

F9::Stop := 1
```

If someone has a different solution how to open files one by one and perform a given action and add it in a loop, please give me some suggestions.

Comment: "Add +1" as in press the down key one more time every round of the loop, or? Also, could you explain what you're trying to do here? What are the hotkeys doing? There sure are better ways than just sending hotkeys, would just need to know what you're trying to do. (I tried to type the hotkeys in explorer myself, but nothing meaningful actually happened)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK i know the answer

```
Send, {Down %A_index%}
```

What i want to do. So I want to Open folder with some texts files (MS Word) and open first one, klick macro (alt+f11) then start macro (f5) and klick (alt + f4) to close macro window and next (alt+f4) to close word window then klick twice enter to accept save changes, then start loop again with next document (loop time = x documents in folder). But im done right now ;p

Anyway if u have any other idea how do things like this in future u can tell ;p
PS Add+1 dostn work ;p